# O que acontece após a sincronização do wait?

Tags: java, thread

Veja só esses dois códigos em threads separadas

Thread A

```
synchronized(objeto) {
    while(condicao)
        objeto.wait();
    //operações
}
```

Thread B

```
synchronized(objeto) {
    condicao = false;
    objeto.notify();
    //operações
}
```

As operações estarão sujeitas a sincronização do bloco ?

Comment: Sim, as operações estarão sujeitas à sincronização do bloco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, desde que `objeto == objeto`.

Um problema corriqueiro, principalmente em sistemas complexos, é que em algum momento você acaba tendo instâncias duplicadas de objetos que deveriam ser *singleton* ou, ao contrário, compartilhar instâncias que não deveriam ser compartilhadas.

Outro problema comum em multi-threading é não controlar corretamente interrupções e timeouts. Não tratar essas coisas pode fazer o programa terminar inesperadamente ou ficar eternamente bloqueado, por exemplo.